# How can i set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I know this type of question has been asked before and i have gone through this but still facing this issue. I was using [this example](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/detect-intent-stream) . But while i run my code i got following exception

> Failed to detect whether we are running on Google Compute Engine.
>                              java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /169.254.169.254:80
>                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:143)
>                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
>                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
>                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
>                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
>                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
>                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
>                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
>                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
>                                  at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:104)
>                                  at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
>                                  at com.google.auth.oauth2.ComputeEngineCredentials.runningOnComputeEngine(ComputeEngineCredentials.java:191)
>                                  at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.tryGetComputeCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:270)
>                                  at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentialsUnsynchronized(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:194)
>                                  at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:112)
>                                  at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:127)
>                                  at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:100)
>                                  at com.google.api.gax.core.GoogleCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(GoogleCredentialsProvider.java:53)
>                                  at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:134)
>                                  at com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.stub.GrpcSessionsStub.create(GrpcSessionsStub.java:75)
>                                  at com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.stub.SessionsStubSettings.createStub(SessionsStubSettings.java:100)
>                                  at com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.SessionsClient.(SessionsClient.java:132)
>                                  at com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.SessionsClient.create(SessionsClient.java:114)
>                                  at com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.SessionsClient.create(SessionsClient.java:106)
>                                  at com.example.lpt_0096.dialogflowv2.MainActivity$MyAsync.detectIntentStream(MainActivity.java:76)
>                                  at com.example.lpt_0096.dialogflowv2.MainActivity$MyAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:61)
>                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
>                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
>                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
>                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
>                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
>   W/System.err: java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
>   W/System.err:     at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:119)
>   W/System.err:     at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:127)
>   W/System.err:     at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:100)
>   W/System.err:     at com.google.api.gax.core.GoogleCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(GoogleCredentialsProvider.java:53)
>   W/System.err:     at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:134)
>   W/System.err:     at com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.stub.GrpcSessionsStub.create(GrpcSessionsStub.java:75)
>   W/System.err:     at com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.stub.SessionsStubSettings.createStub(SessionsStubSettings.java:100)
>   W/System.err:     at com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.SessionsClient.(SessionsClient.java:132)
>   W/System.err:     at com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.SessionsClient.create(SessionsClient.java:114)
>   W/System.err:     at com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.SessionsClient.create(SessionsClient.java:106)
>   W/System.err:     at com.example.lpt_0096.dialogflowv2.MainActivity$MyAsync.detectIntentStream(MainActivity.java:76)
>   W/System.err:     at com.example.lpt_0096.dialogflowv2.MainActivity$MyAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:61)
>   W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
>   W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
>   W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
>   W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
>   W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

from where can i set environment variable in android studio, I am windows user

Comment: `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=path/to/your/service_accont_key_file.json` you may need to add this in the environment variable `path`.  Should get the `json` file from here https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started . Also if you don't know how set path check this https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm.

Comment: @sunilsunny Could you post this as an answer? For future reference of the community.

Comment: @Mangu Why not :) added as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

From the error

> java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not
>   available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine.
>   Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
>   must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials
>
> See
>   https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials
>   for more information.

You may need to add this in the environment variable path `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=path/to/your/service_accont_key_file.json`. And should get the json file from here https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started . Also if you don't know how to set environment variable path you can check this https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: I have done what you have suggested but still it throw exception. My Question still remains there ... How can i achieve this in android